# When the page load for the first time , webdriver takes a long time to find the first element

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver / java for my application testing , I am facing a strange issue.

When I do get of an  URL and then try to find or wait for an element , it takes long to execute that nearly 6 minutes.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get(getApplicationURL());

Boolean isPresent = driverUtil.waitAndCheckPresent(20,By.xpath(<my xpath>));
.......................................................
 .................................................



      public boolean waitAndCheckPresent(int timeout, By by){

        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
            WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;  
        }

    }
```

Details:-
FF version:- 17-24
Webdriver :- 2.35.0

I have no idea why it is hanging for so long before proceeding , as I mentioned I see this only when the page loads for the first time , [ The page which is a login page comes up in 10 secs with the input fields]

Comment: Debug and check which line is taking so much time

Comment: After debugging I found that ..whenever there is a driver.find() , or the control is waiting for some element , it is not able to find it...even though the element is present and this happens only when the UI login page comes up and when the HOme page loads , it works smoothly after that....

Comment: Check what the server (i.e the Selenium Server JAR that you launch) is doing. It'll log each request & response it deals with. See where it is getting stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

You can still speedup your script execution by waiting for presence (not waiting for visibility) of expected element for say 5-8 sec and then sending *window.stop()* JS Script (to stop loading further elements ) without waiting for entire page to load 
or catching the timeout exception for page load after 5-8 seconds then calling window.stop()

Because if the page not adopted lazy loading technique (loading only visible element and loading rest of element only after scroll) it loads each element before returning window.ready state so it will be slower if any of the element takes longer time to render.