# Selenium WebDriverWait takes too long to find an element on the page

Tags: python, selenium

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.ID,
    'something-important',
)))
thing = driver.find_element_by_id(
    'something-important',
).text
```

At this point, I've just followed a link to a new page, so the the page is loading, and I can't just immediately get the 'thing' out of the new page. I know I need to use a wait here, but the wait takes far too long to find the element.

I *do* want a timeout, because the page might take a long time to load, and I need to handle that. Also if it takes too long, I want it to fail with a timeout exception.

However, in the vast majority of cases, the element is in the page within 3 seconds, but Selenium blocks for around 30 seconds waiting for it to be present. I can see that it is, and I can confirm in the browser that it's there, it just takes ages for the wait to return. How do I stop this? If the element is there within 3 seconds, this should stop blocking very shortly afterwards.

I have tried manually setting a poll frequency of 0.5 seconds, which is apparently the default anyway with the Python selenium bindings, but that doesn't help.

This question seems very similar to [When the page load for the first time , webdriver takes a long time to find the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430829/when-the-page-load-for-the-first-time-webdriver-takes-a-long-time-to-find-the) - but that one hasn't been answered, and the information there so far hasn't helped me get to a solution yet.

Comment: Does this mean you just want to set the timeout to  say 5 seconds and catch the timeout Exception?

Comment: No, I want to catch the timeout if the page actually times out loading, but I want to get the element as soon as possible if it is there, which almost all the time it is.

Comment: From the docs it looks like you are using the correct thing.  Have you tried any other methods?  I've never heard of WebDriverWait until I read this, and when I've run into this problem in the past I just check for the elements presence in a loop and use time.sleep - My version of poll frequency

Comment: From reading the documentation, WebDriverWait is the supported and preferred way of polling until an element is present or visible, or until other conditions are met.

Comment: which is not working for you - I understand that it is the preferred way, but why not try something new(time.sleep) and see if that works?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this would mess anything up but in your prior code do you call driver.implicitly_wait()?  I have a feeling it could mess up the poll frequency

Comment: I'm not calling implicitly_wait anywhere. Doing a sleep might work, but it's a hack and I'd rather figure out the reason this doesn't work and solve it properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57411/discussion-between-zjs-and-danpalmer).